# How can I find an element in Specified area in document?

Tags: javascript, image

I'm beginner in JavaScript; I need when click on an a element find `img` element in parent of a tag, how can I done this without jQuery?

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle with your HTML to see the DOM structure

Comment: You need to learn HTML DOM (Document Object Model).

Answer (score 1):

Your question is fairly unclear, but the answer is basically: Use the methods defined in the DOM: [DOM3 Core](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/) | [Selectors API Level 1](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-api/), depending on what browsers you need to support.

For instance: On [most modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=queryselector), you could do this:

```
document.getElementById("some_element_id").addEventListener("click", function() {
    // Look in parent for all `img` elements
    var imgs = this.parentNode.querySelectorAll("img");

    // ...do something with them...
}, false);
```

Or as mplungjan points out in a comment below, you can use `getElementsByTagName`, which is supported by older browsers:

```
document.getElementById("some_element_id").addEventListener("click", function() {
    // Look in parent for all `img` elements
    var imgs = this.parentNode.querySelectorAll("img");

    // ...do something with them...
}, false);
```

Or if you don't want to give the element you click an `id`, you can replace `document.getElementById("some_element_id")` with `document.querySelector('any CSS selector here')` to select the first matching element. (Again only on most modern browsers.)

---

Side note: You can do everything using JavaScript and the DOM, but frankly it'll be a lot less work, much more cross-browser compatible, and a lot more fun if you use a decent library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com), [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/), [Closure](http://code.google.com/closure/library), or [any of several others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JavaScript_libraries). :-)

Comment: why not getElementsByTagName which covers more browsers and actually has a better name for what we are looking for

Comment: @mplungjan: Mostly because I tend to forget about it. :-) But even IE8 has `querySelector` now. Thanks for the reminder, though, I've added that.

Comment: And I forget querySelectorAll myself :) You are correct http://caniuse.com/queryselector